# Delete substrings by given list of pairs of indices

Tags: python, string

I have the following rather simple snippet:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):                                                                             
  '''                                                                                                                   
  s: original input string                                                                                   
  blocks: list of indices (start, end) to be deleted                                                                
                                                                                                                        
  return string `out` where blocks are deleted from s                                                      
  '''                                                                                                                   
  out = ''                                                                                                              
  p = 0                                                                                                                 
  for start, end in blocks:                                                                                             
      out += s[p:start]                                                                                               
      p = end                                                                                                           
  out += s[p:]                                                                                                        
  return out
```

This function takes a string `s` and delete all `s[start:end]` from `s`, where pairs of indices `(start, end)` are given in a list `blocks`.

Is there a builtin function somewhere that does the same thing?

---

There is an assumption in my code:

`blocks` are sorted by the first index in ascending order (done by `list.sort()` in-place)

As for if the blocks can overlap, in my use case I ensure they don't before invoking the function. But for fun we can also assume they do.

Comment: can the `(start, end)` blocks overlap ?

Comment: No ... as a general rule there are not builtin functions for every single arbitrary thing you need to do ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach transforms `blocks` into a set of indices which I call `exclude`. After that, loop through the string and exclude those characters whose index is in the `exclude` set. I am using set instead of list because it nicely handles the duplicates (in case of overlapping ranges).

## Build the `exclude` set

Given an unordered, potentially overlapped list of ranges:

```
blocks = [(5, 7), (2, 4), (6, 10)]
```

I want to convert this into:

```
exclude = {2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

How:

```
exclude = set()
for block in blocks:
    exclude.update(range(*block))
```

## Putting it all together

Here is my code and a little example at the end. Note that I chose to rename the function since this function is generic enough to work with string, list, tuple, and other iterable objects, not just strings. Also, because the function returns a list, when dealing with string, we need to join the list of characters back together.

```
def delete_blocks(iterable, blocks):                                                                             
    exclude = set()
    for block in blocks:
        exclude.update(range(*block))
    return [cell for i, cell in enumerate(iterable) if i not in exclude]

# Try it out
test_string = '0123456789abc'
blocks = [(5, 7), (2, 4), (6, 10)]
result = ''.join(delete_blocks(test_string, blocks))

print('Before: {!r}'.format(test_string))
print('Blocks:', blocks)
print('After: {!r}'.format(result))
```

## Update: implement `delete_substring_blocks`

To really answer Mai's question, I implemented `delete_substring_blocks` using `delete_blocks`:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):
    return ''.join(delete_blocks(s, blocks))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is unspecified we must assume that the list of blocks may contain overlaps.

A relatively inefficient expression, but one that will handle overlapping and non-sorted blocks, is:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):
    return ''.join(
        [c for i, c in enumerate(s) 
         if not any(blk for blk in blocks 
                    if i >= blk[0] and i < blk[1])])
```

Here we simply test each character's position to see if it is within any of the block intervals and accept it if it is not.

Here is an example with an overlapping block:

```
>>> delete_substring_blocks(
        "hello there how are you", 
        [[0, 3], [7, 9], [7, 10]])
'lo te how are you'
```

As you appear to find this expression unreadable, here it is broken down a little more:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):
    def check_pos(i):
        return not any(1 for start, end in blocks 
                       if i >= start and i < end)

    return ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(s) 
                    if check_pos(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the blocks in reversed sorted order, or the intended parts of the string will change places and the block indices will be invalid.

It would be something like:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):
  '''
      s: original input string
      blocks: list of indices (start, end) to be deleted

      return string `out` where blocks are deleted from orig_str
  '''
  for start, end in reversed(sorted(blocks)):
    s = s[:start] + s[end:]
  return s
```

Comment: Not sure here, but is the `s = s[:...]` intentionally changed from the OPs `s += s[:...]`

Comment: This function will not handle overlapping blocks

Comment: (1) `tmp` and `p` are unused. (2) This code will not work because every iteration `s` becomes shorter. I suggest you test it.

Comment: I didn't think about overlapping blocks. I guess that the best solution will be to create a boolean bitmap of the characters to recover.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on a bitmap. It can handle overlapping blocks:

```
def delete_substring_blocks(s, blocks):
    # create a bitmap with False for characters to be deleted
    preserve = [True] * len(s)
    for i, j in blocks:
        preserve[i:j] = False

    result = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if preserve[i]:
            result.append(c)

    return ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

No.  What you're asking for is fairly specific.  You could easily one line it if you wanted to specify the parts of the string you wanted to keep (as opposed to delete).

```
>>> string = 'my long string'
>>> ''.join([string[s:e] for s, e in [(0,3), (8, 14)]])
'my string'
```

Comment: This will not handle overlapping blocks, and assumes they are sorted, and doesn't answer the question actually asked.

Comment: @donkopotamus  My answer is correct.  The only question asked was if there was a built in function that does what the posted function does.  The only correct answer is No.

Comment: @donkopotamus  Also, the overlapping blocks requirement wasn't mentioned in the question.  It was a contrived limitation that you imposed.

Comment: I don't think it is contrived really ... if you are given an arbitrary list of blocks then it is contrived to assume that they are *not* overlapping.  Making a function more secure against its inputs is always a good thing, you never know what the user might provide.

Comment: You are extracting the blocks I wanna delete... In your example, the correct output should be `'long '`. Remember, blocks are indices `to be deleted`.

Comment: @mai See my answer -- *specify the parts of the string you wanted to keep (as opposed to delete)*