# Excluding intervals from a real number line

Tags: python, algorithm

A long time ago I asked the following question:

[Python: delete substring by indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144498/python-delete-substring-by-indices)

Last week I was asked a very similar question, but with continuous real-number line.

Imagine you are given an interval `(X, Y)`, and a bunch of sub-intervals `blocks=[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]`. Your goal is to find a list of intervals `remaining=[(a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..]` that is (1) in `(X, Y)`, but (2) not in any of the sub-intervals in `blocks`. The intervals in `blocks` can overlap.

In other words, the function signature looks something like:

````
def delete_blocks_from_interval(X, Y, blocks):
    ```
    X: start of the given interval
    Y: end of the given interval
    blocks: list of intervals (x, y) to be removed, can overlap

    returns remaining = [(a, b), ...] intervals remaining after removal of blocks
    ```
    pass
````

I can construct a graph of connected intervals in `blocks`, and find both the minimum of the start and the maximum of end for each connected component in the graph. But this is quadratic in length of `blocks`. I wonder if there is a better-runtime algorithm.

Please also discuss what code routine you think is more efficient for the algorithm if you will.

Many many thanks.

---

As requested, please consider the following illustrative inputs:

1. `X = -1`
2. `Y = 20`
3. `blocks = [(1, 10), (4, 5), (9, 11), (16, 17.5)]`
4. the expected output is `remaining = [(-1, 1), (11, 16), (17.5, 20)]`

Comment: Can the `blocks` overlap?

Comment: Good question. Yes, they can.

Comment: Can you provide some input / output pairs?

Comment: @norok2 edited.

Comment: Will the *sub*-intervals in `blocks` always be sorted - `(smaller,larger)`?

Comment: @wwii Yes.sub-intervals in `blocks` always be sorted from smaller to larger..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be linear run-time in number of blocks

```
import bisect

def delete_blocks_from_interval(range_start, range_end, blocks):
    blocks = sorted(blocks)

    # check if the interval overlaps with blocks,
    # if so, truncate the block lists, reset end points if required
    start_idx = bisect.bisect_left([b[0] for b in blocks],range_start)
    end_idx = bisect.bisect_left([b[0] for b in blocks],range_end)
    blocks = blocks[start_idx:end_idx]
    if blocks[0][0] < range_start:
        blocks[0][0] = range_start 
    if blocks[-1][1] > range_end:
        blocks[-1][1] = range_end

    # emit the first gap, if any
    if range_start < blocks[0][0]:
        yield (range_start, blocks[0][0])

    # loop through till the end of the blocks
    end = blocks[0][1]
    for block in blocks[1:]:
        if end < block[0]:
            yield (end, block[0])
            end = block[1]
        elif end < block[1]:
            end = block[1]

    # emit the last gap, if any
    if range_end > blocks[-1][1]:
        yield (blocks[-1][1], range_end)

blocks = [(1, 10), (4, 5), (9, 11), (16, 17.5)]
list(delete_blocks_from_interval(-1, 20, blocks))
```

Answer (score 1):

[python-ranges](https://pypi.org/project/python-ranges/) is a library I wrote that excels at this particular use case. It isn't the most efficient code you could possibly write (it essentially uses `@wwii`'s algorithm below, in fact) but it is nice and terse.

```
from ranges import Range, RangeSet

...

def delete_blocks_from_interval(X, Y, blocks):
    # make a Range
    orig = Range(X, Y)
    # make a RangeSet out of the 2-tuple blocks
    #   (using the unpacking operator to interpret 2-tuples as positional args for Range())
    # and then find the difference from the original set 
    #   (like with sets, the - operator is a shorthand for .difference())
    remaining = orig - RangeSet(
        Range(*block) for block in blocks
    )
    # return each range in the RangeSet as a tuple
    return [(rng.start, rng.end) for rng in remaining.ranges()]
```

Comment: Would you kindly include a few words on how is your library implemented?

Comment: @Mai I've edited the short version into my question - it's similar to wwii's answer below - but if you want [here's the relevant source code](https://github.com/Superbird11/ranges/blob/master/ranges/ranges.py#L730)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
def delete_blocks_from_interval(a, b, blocks):
    sorted_blocks = sorted(blocks)
    for i, (c, d) in enumerate(sorted_blocks):
        if a <= c <= b:
            yield (a, c)
            if d > a:
               a = d
            for (e, f) in sorted_blocks[i + 1:]:
                if e <= a <= f:
                    a = f
                elif e > a:
                    break
    if a <= d <= b:
        yield (d, b)


blocks = ((1, 10), (4, 5), (9, 11), (16, 17.5))
print(list(delete_blocks_from_interval(-1, 20, blocks)))
# (-1, 1), (11, 16), (17.5, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the `blocks`;
- check if there is a gap between `X` and item 0 of the first block; save if there is;
- iterate over blocks in pairs,

  - get the first and second item
  - if item 1 of the *first* block is less than item 0 of the *second* block,

    - save this interval (*first*[1],*second*[0]) ;
  - or if they overlap,

    - compare the last items,
    - if the last item of the *second* tuple is bigger than the last item of the *first* - expand the *first* tuple range,
    - get the *third*/next item, repeat the comparison(s)
- repeat til you get to the end of the (X,Y) interval or you run out of `blocks`.

Comment: What is the key by which you sort `blocks`? The start or the end of the sub-intervals?

Comment: [By default will sort on the first item, then go to the next item to *break ties*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: What if you have `[(1, 10), (4, 5)]` as `blocks`? Do you save `(10, 4)`?

Comment: Thank you for the editing, adding "or if they overlap, get the third item, repeat the comparison". In the case of `[(1, 10), (4, 5)]` being `blocks`, there is not third item. The correct interval to be removed is simply `(1, 10)`, which is the first one. Please consider completely rewriting your solution or withdraw because of correctness problem.

Comment: See the edit. Maybe I misunderstood the question - I thought the intent was to *find* portions of the XY span that are not *covered by* the small intervals in `blocks` - so for (1,10) and (4,5) the interval 1-10 is *covered* so there is nothing to do until you find a gap between 10 and something greater than ten

Comment: If there is no third/next item, the iteration stops.

Comment: Thank you for editing again. I believe you have to check the overlapping condition before checking if item 1 of the first block is less than item 0 of the second block, otherwise `(10, 4)` would be saved. Please consider writing pseudo-code to demonstrate your solution, as the words don't seem to suffice so far.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your main idea now. I believe your "pseudocode" is still incorrect. Using my example above, the first remaining sub-interval should be `(-1, 1)`. The start (-1) is not in `blocks`, therefore you have to check `X`. The end is also a special case. But I understand SO is for help only. Maybe I shouldn't emphasize so much on details and correctness. You have been a great help. I won't bug you anymore.