# Remove parts of string based on list of index chunks

Tags: python

I have a list of index 'chunks' that I need to remove from a string. An example:

```
list_to_remove = [(0, 4), (10, 14)]

test_text = "This is a test sentence"
```

The removal should be characters from index 0 to 4, and characters from index 10 to 14.

After removal the result should be:

```
test_text_clean = "is a sentence"
```

I have thought about looping through the chunks in the list and slicing the string, however removing something from the string would change the position of the remaining characters, meaning my indexes would no longer be correct for the remaining removals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop and slice from the end to avoid changing the indices of the sections to remove, just reverse `list_to_remove`

```
list_to_remove = [(0, 4), (10, 14)]
test_text = "This is a test sentence"
for t in list_to_remove[::-1]:
    test_text = test_text[:t[0]] + test_text[t[1] + 1:]
print(test_text) # is a sentence
```

Comment: The linked question's solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144498/delete-substrings-by-given-list-of-pairs-of-indices works, but this is also a good option - reversing the list is a nice idea!

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this, it won't be super efficient since you are iterating over individual characters but it should work:

```py
clean_text = ''.join(
    i for index,i in enumerate(test_text) if not any(
        j[0]<=index<j[1] for j in list_to_remove
    )
)
```

Comment: This is not a one-liner-contest. Please make your code understandable so that everyone can learn something. And break it at round about the 80th char.